# Calculate column value from function

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I have a table that is being used by an old program, clarion. In clarion when you add a table, it makes some kind of dictionary that maps the table. To create this mapping, the columns must be in order. Clarion doesn't read it by name, but it does read it by order and size.

I have to 'alter' a column in table. However, that column needs to be calculated by a function:

```
ALTER FUNCTION uf_gifValue (@aID int)
RETURNS varchar(8)
    WITH SCHEMABINDING
BEGIN
    DECLARE @returnValue varchar(8)
    SELECT @returnValue = ISNULL(C.columnName, '')
    FROM
        dbo.TableA AS A (this is old table)
    LEFT JOIN dbo.TableB AS B
    ON  A.BId= B.BId
    LEFT JOIN dbo.TableC AS C
    ON  B.CId= C.CId
    WHERE
        A.AId= @aID
    RETURN ISNULL(@returnValue , '')
END 
GO
```

The table that is affected have schema something like:

```
Table
{
column1
.
.
.
.
AffectedColumn
.
.
.
.
AId int identity(1,1) PRIMARY KEY}
```

First I tried to make the function, make the temp table, drop the constraints on the old table and make a temp table with the calculated field. Then, I raised the constraints on the temp table and inserted from the old table to the temp table. Lastly, I dropped the old table and renamed the temp table to the old table name. This method did not work because the old table is referenced by a function and cannot be dropped.

Next, I tried to make a function that does nothing and returns ''. I made a temp table with the calculated field and dropped the constraints of the old table. Then, I raised constraints on the temp table and inserted from the old table to the temporary table, dropped the old table and renamed the temp table to the old table name. Then, I altered the function so that it returns the proper value.
This issue I had with this method is that I cannot alter calculated column or function while it is being referenced.

The last thing that I tried was to drop the constraints on the old table, make the function, add the calculated column, and add columns that are after the one that is affected in order to preserve column order. Then, I dropped columns that I are between the affected column and the new columns, including the old column. However, this did not work because I cannot drop 'AID' since it is after the affected column.

Please Note: The value of the column is being calculated from other tables than the table containing the column.

Is there a way that I will be able to alter this column to contain the value as calculated by my function?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you rename the table and add a view named by the old table returning everything and maybe even a result of a function evaluated in real time. This kind of simple view is editable.

Comment: was thinking of that, but view is rather slow due i have some milions of data